# How do I remove excess whitespace being generated by an EL tag in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, el

The idea is to print the authors of each book and to add a comma in between each author. The generated HTML is adding tons of white space, which creates a single space between the comma and the next name. See screenshot. I'm trying to remove that excess space.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <c:forEach items="${book.authors}" var="author" varStatus="loop">
            ${author.firstName} ${author.middleInitials} ${author.lastName}
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${author.postNominalInitials != null}">
                    ${author.postNominalInitials}
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
            <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to remove the space after each author's name (and eventually replace the final comma with 'and')

[image]

Here's the readout from the Google inspector, where I'm seeing the additional   white space being added.

[image]

Thank you for the help!